# React Native Maps custom marker is not touchable after region change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I am using custom markers with React Native Maps. On the initial load touching the markers will reveal the callout (title and description) of the marker. However, after dragging the map to a new region, the markers are no longer touchable. To show the marker's title and description after changing regions, the user must tap exactly on the marker coordinate.

While dragging the map, the marker images flash in and out. I think this might have something to do with them becoming untouchable. How can I prevent this?

```
<MapView
  style={styles.homeMapView}
  region={this.state.currentLocation}
  onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
  showsUserLocation={true}
  onPress={(evt) => console.log(evt.nativeEvent.coordinate)}
>
  {this.state.nearbyLocations.map((marker, key) => (
    <MapView.Marker
      key={marker.id}
      coordinate={marker.coordinate}
      title={marker.title}
      description={marker.description}
      onPress={(evt) => console.log('pressed ', evt)}
      image={require('../Public/existingPins.png')}
      centerOffset={{x: 0, y: -20}}
    />
  ))}
</MapView>
```

**EDIT**

It seems the mark is actually stil touchable after the map region is changed. The marker's `onPress` function still console logs every time the marker is touched even if the map region changes. After reading the [React Native Maps docs](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md) a little more, it looks like the area that `showCallout` can be invoked by touching is the only part that shrinks. This touchable area only shrinks if a custom marker is used.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use onSelect prop instead of onPress prop?